# Remove cell accessories with Mono Touch

Tags: mono, xamarin.ios, cell, accessory

How can i remove all the cell accessories within a table with the press of a button?

I wanted to go through all the table rows and set the accessory for each cell to none. To do this you need to know the indexPaths to be able to get the rows. This isn't possible within Mono Touch (but is in native code!).

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: MonoTouch bindings are generally low-level and match the ObjectiveC API closely - so everything should be possible. Please show us the objective-c code and we'll be able to help you (edit your post to include it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have the button cause a table refresh, and set some flag that will tell GetCell() whether or not the accessory should be drawn.